# Core Data: crash when last window is closed

Tags: objective-c, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

I get invariably this error when I close the last window of my app:

> Application Specific Information: objc_msgSend() selector name:
>   respondsToSelector: objc[42729]: garbage collection is OFF
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00007fff8cc9a150 objc_msgSend_vtable5
>   + 16 1   com.apple.AppKit                 0x00007fff8fbca814 -[NSApplication supplementalTargetForAction:sender:] + 63 2   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8fab91e4
>   _objectFromResponderChainWhichRespondsToAction + 155 3   com.apple.AppKit                 0x00007fff8fab8feb
>   _NSTargetForSendAction + 3255 4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fab832f -[NSApplication targetForAction:to:from:] + 682 5 
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff8fab7e00 -[NSMenu
>   _enableItem:] + 403

I confess that the document nib has two windows. I want the "auxiliary window" to be closed and deallocated when the main window is closed. How should I do? Maybe these errors com from here… I'm using Core Data and ARC.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried with the zombies on?

Comment: I tried Instruments / Zombies. The little rascal is a NSTableColumn, targeted by the application. But how can I know a bit more? What column, into what window? Why the last window (others close without error)?

Answer (score 0):

I found something which seems to solve the problem. But I don't understand what's happening and I really dislike this.

In IB, the file's owner has a "window" outlet who points to the document window; but there is no @property NSWindow window; in the default code of the NS(Persistent)Document.

I had to make a panel a "child window" of the doc's main window, so I add a @property NSWindow mainWindow. The new "mainWindow" outlet points to the same window as the "window" outlet.

And suddenly no more crash, no more zombie. What happened? I'm baffled.

After reflexion: I have added a pointer to the document window, so the ARC counter never reaches zero. I suppose I had a missing reference somewhere to the _window of the NSDocument, which is now balanced by my outlet.